# Apollo - Link client to multiple graphql schema registeries

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo, graphql-js

So we have multiple graphQL services & each service have its own schema which we are pushing to apollo registry each time we make any change to the schema. On the client side we point to multiple graphQL services & we need schema for linting purpose.

We used apollo registry for this purpose but we've noticed that it works perfectly for only one apollo registry, I was wondering if there is anyway we can point to multiple apollo registries & could use it in the client for linting purpose.

We've the following `apollo-config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    service: "graphql-service1@variant"
  }
}
```

And I was hopping to do something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  client: {
    service: ["graphql-service1@variant", "other-graphql-service@variant"]
  }
}
```

I am using `apollo service:push` command to push schema to registry. The problem will also be resolved if we have a way to merge the schema in registry when pushing it to registry. May be another command like `apollo service:merge` which would merge the schema in the registry instead of overwriting it.

The apollo documentation says that its supposed to be central hub for all the schema from all the graphql services but I am not able to find a way to push all my schema to this central hub (registry) from all the services (basically a merged schema)

Thanks in anticipation